Incorporating version control to Google Apps Script for shared code across multiple projects
I’ve created a large Apps Script project that I’m very proud of. It’s essentially a budget spreadsheet that has most if not all of the functionality of YNAB (you need a budget). Throughout the course of its development, I had one template sheet that I performed the development work on and versions that I used were copies of that template. The same followed if I shared the template with others to help me test and point out bugs.
This process very quickly introduced some inefficiencies. If changes were identified, I would make the necessary edits to the template file and manually instruct anyone with a copy of the sheet template to update the necessary apps script code, manually, which proved to be a huge headache. I am looking for a way to streamline this process as the number of users of this sheet and the code could theoretically increase exponentially.
What I am envisioning is developing my code locally on my computer in VS code and having that code be tied to a GitHub repository. Additionally I would want that local code to be connected to a sheet/apps script project development template that I use for testing after which I can “deploy” or push that code to all sheets that use that code from the repository.
Is such a workflow possible? I believe it is but I can’t really find any step by step instructions on how to set that up. The closest thing I found is here but it doesn’t really address some of the key questions I have on setting that up.
If I can accomplish this, it would make development so much easier for this and any subsequent project I produce.

Remember that questions on Stack Overflow should be about a specific practical problem unique to programming. Questions about the setup of a development process are too broad. Please focus on using something specific. You might have to start by reviewing the CLASP commands, their options and the artifacts, i.e. .clasp.json and .claspignore files and the commands used to create and modify them.

This might help https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/616

See Add-ons overview. You'd probably want to build an editor add-on.

@doubleunary this doesn't seem to relate to what my needs are here. Do you have an example of how this is applicable to my use case?

@J_code Editor addons are published to the marketplace. Updates are seamless. Another alternative is libraries. Where users can use head version or any other version  they choose to.

@J_code when you deploy a script project as an add-on, you can use that same add-on in many spreadsheets. When you update the code in the script project and redeploy, all targets get the update automatically.

I see, that's really powerful. Thank you!
